# Mistakes in my facts? (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

```
parent(_,_).
descendant(X,Y):- parent(Y,X).
descendant(edward,david).
descendant(malcolm,mark).
descendant(edward,therese).
descendant(malcolm,nathalie).
descendant(matthew,raymond).
descendant(matthew,nadine).
sibling(X,Y):- descendant(X,Z), descendant(Y,Z).
sibling(edward,kevin).
sibling(sean,vicky).
sibling(vicky,edward).
sibling(malcolm,claude).
sibling(matthew,stephania).
sibling(matthew,kurt).
```

The problem here is that for some reason the code isn't working. What I mean by that is that no matter what queries I input regarding this code it always returns true
(I'm not including all the atoms in my program because it would just be a simple male(X) or female(X) where all of the people being included are covered, saving you some time)
An example of what I mean: ?- sibling(edward,david). true.
Sorry if I'm making no sense but if somebody would tell me what I'm doing wrong here I would really appreciate it...

parent/2 is a direct predicate (by direct I mean that it isn't defined in terms of other predicates) and my problem with it is that if I changed it to parent(X,Y) I'd get a singleton error

Comment: if it isn't defined in terms of other predicates, it means that it is defined in terms of facts. No need to add anything to the facts then. the facts of form `parent(A,B)` must exist somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line in your code (`parent(_,_).`) will always succeed.

Therefore, procedure `sibling/s` which uses `descendant/s` which uses `parent/s` will also always succeed at least once.

You should remove that clause (`parent(_,_).`) as it seems to state that any two persons are parents.

Comment: The thing is my assignment requires me to include parent/2 as a direct variable and if I change it to parent(X,Y) I get a singleton variable error

Comment: @EdwardBamber Your previous comment does not make sense. A predicate is not a variable, and I don't know what a "direct" variable is supposed to be anyway. Clarify your question, or even better, edit it to include the original requirement (not re-phrased by you).

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to prolog (and declarative paradigms in general)
I'll get to arranging this now